# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

I get this error:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' (most likely due to a circular import)

Code:

```
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
print(now)
```

[image]

Comment: does your demo.py file is used by another files? the code you have attached should work.
please also fix your question to look better: attach normally the image and put your code with code quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry it is my first-time post
yes there no is a file named with the demo I make sure that 
even if I rename it as something like "jhbfdhfdsf" it's not working and giving me the same error

Answer (score 6):

Look at the error carefully you have a file named datetime.py in your parent directory (32_automated_email).

Change the name and it will work fine. Don't name a file same as a python module.