# Specific file extension in os.walk()

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have the following code:

```
path = "/path/to/directory/"
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        folder = os.path.basename(dirpath)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(file)
```

The only problem is that I would like to filter and get the information only for the mp4 files, excluding the others from the search.

I tried to add *.mp4 at the end of `path` without success, how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.walk()` requires a single directory argument, so you can't use wildcards. You could filter the contents of `filenames` but it's probably easier to just do this:

```
path = "/path/to/directory/"
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if not filename.endswith(".mp4"):
            continue
        file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        folder = os.path.basename(dirpath)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(file)
```

Alternatively, you could use the more modern and preferred `pathlib`; this will find all `.mp4` files recursively:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = "/path/to/directory/"
for file in Path(path).rglob("*.mp4"):
    [....]
```

Each `file` object will have attributes and methods you can use to obtain information about the file, e.g. `file.name`, `file.stat()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pathlib suggestion, but I'm getting this error: ```ImportError: cannot import name 'Path' from partially initialized module 'pathlib' (most likely due to a circular import)```

Comment: This is usually because of a name conflict between your script and a Python module. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393604/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-datetime-has-no-attribute-dateti) for example.